# Event Grid Delivery Properties Is Secret property not working

Tags: azure, paas

We are trying to use Delivery Properties in Event Grid. In Delivery Properties we are adding one dynamic property. When we enable Is Secret property, Microsoft link shows it should be not be visible in the portal. But it is does not work as expected. We are able to view that header. Can anyone suggest, IS that because we have access to that ADO or tenant. or something else.